# How to i fix unexpected symbol near ')

Tags: lua

[script:dillen_mecota] Error parsing script @dillen_mecotablet/server/main.lua in resource dillen_mecotablet: @dillen_mecotablet/server/main.lua:68: unexpected symbol near ')'

```
RegisterNetEvent('dillen_mecotablet:setMecano')
AddEventHandler('dillen_mecotablet:setMecano', function()
    local jobGrade = xPlayer.getJob().grade
    xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    if xPlayer.getJob().name == 'taxi' then
        xPlayer.setJob('mecano', jobGrade)
    end
end)

ESX.RegisterServerCallback('dillen_mecotablet:getInDuty', function(source, callback)
    local player = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    local personalNumber = player.characterId
    local job = player.job['name']

    local coworkers = {}
    local Players = ESX.GetPlayers()

    for _, item in pairs(Players) do
        local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_)

        if xplayer ~= nil then
        if xPlayer['job']['name'] == job then
            table.insert(coworkers, {
                name = xPlayer.character['firstname'] .. " " .. xPlayer.character['lastname'], 
                phone = xPlayer.get('phoneNumber'),
                grade_text = xPlayer["job"]["grade_label"]
            })
        end
    end

    callback(coworkers)


end)  ---- This is the 68 line
```

I try to delete the ) but it dindt work

Comment: Think you are missing an end above callback

Comment: Yep, see line `if xplayer ~= nil then`. Indent the block after that properly and you should see why an end is missing above the callback.